# Google+ button - opengraph image not resolving

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, google-plus, google-plus-one

Google+ button is not using the specified opengraph image.
Facebook does.

I've seen one post about the image size being a factor.

Is there any documentation that specifies the correct image size to use with google+ and opengraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google+ FAQ](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#faqs): **Why isn't my +Snippet image appearing in the share bubble?**

> Images that are too small or not square enough will not be included in
>   the +Snippet, even if explicitly referenced using schema.org microdata
>   or Open Graph markup. Specifically, the height must be at least 120px,
>   and if the width is less than 100px, then the aspect ratio must be no
>   greater than 3.0.

Comment: but it does't says about max dimensions. 500x500px is okay? What if user will use 2048x1159px picture size?

Comment: Apparently [9999x9999px](http://www.allmyplus.com/sharetest/?s=9999) images will work. Never tried anything bigger.